# Post request Http call with data as Array of Objects from JS(Bixby capsule endpoint) to PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, bixby, bixbystudio

When I'm sending the post request with JS ,Its sending success response.But table not updating.Only one of below postman request works and updates.

I'm having following http call in js.

**JS code**

```
var url = "my url";

var obj = {
'wid': 4001,
'sc': 600
};

var data = [];
data.push(obj);

var params = {
"method": "update",
"userid": "94525",
"data": JSON.stringify(data) //tried with or without stringify data
}; 

let options = {
format: 'json',
headers: {
  'accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
};

var response = http.postUrl(url, params, options);
```

**Php function code :**

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$item) {
    $GLOBALS[$key] = $item; 
}

function isValidParams($params) {
    $flag = true;
    foreach ($params as $key) {
        if(!isset($GLOBALS[$key]) || empty($GLOBALS[$key])) {
            $flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $flag;
}
function update() {
    $flag = isValidParams(["userid", "data"]);
    if(!$flag) return;

    global $mysqli, $response, $userid, $data;
    
    $wordIdString = "";
    $sc = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $word) {
        $wordIdString .= ",".$word["wid"];
        $sc += $word["sc"];
    }
    if($sc > 0) {
        $query = "UPDATE users_new SET pWIds = CONCAT(pWIds, '$wordIdString'), sc = (sc + $sc) WHERE userid = $userid";
        $res = $mysqli->query($query);
    }
    $response["check"] = "success";
}
```

Below is the screenshot of postman which works perfect and updates.

[image]

And the below doesn't work.
[image]

I don't get the difference .Is it the same reason my js also not working as expected.

Note : Cannot change the php code ,only suggest changes on js.

My same url without array of object as data are working fine.Only this creating the issue.I don't get why.Thank you.

Comment: Abhishek Sarkar can you show us the isValidParams() function and the code that populates $data? without it.. it is impossible to understand what is going on.

Comment: @MiguelCosta check updated ,anything more you need.

Comment: you forgot the $data definition..

Comment: ohh my bad, so data from the superglobal.. sorry

Comment: @MiguelCosta yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abhishek Sarkar this is how your post's are interpreted by php

[image]

when you post [{"wid":4001,"sc":600}] you are sending a string to php. In order to convert it to an array (in php) you would need to adjust the code (something you can't do)

Now about your php code:
php expects that all the items inside data are an array and you are sending an object: 
{'wid': 4001,'sc': 600} expected ['wid'=>4001,'sc'=>600]

I'm guessing that this is the reason why it doesn't work.

[EDITED] After some chatting and some testing with Abhishek Sarkar we found that this is the correct way to post the data:

```
var params = { 
  "method": "update", 
  "userid": "94525", 
  "data[0][wid]": "4001", 
  "data[0][sc]": "600", 
};
```

for future references: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/JavaScriptAPI/http#httpgeturlurl-options

Comment: nop..
https://screencast.com/t/ucSoh16K
 and that code you pasted doesn't make much sense.. you shouldn't use push on obj because you need to define a key, and that is not the way you use push on JS.. the code I pasted is not something you would normally do, but in this case it might work..

Comment: I dont get why its showing empty array // data[[]] in my case with above.Still thanks for your response.

Comment: it is empty because the we are adding properties to the object and not values.
Since you told that you already tried all the options to add values, then the last resort is to try to see if the logic can do a properties to value conversions..

Comment: by the way have you tried removing  the headers and not "stringifying" data?

Comment: tried just now without "stringifying" and headers but still didn't work.

Comment: lets debug what you are sending to the server.. can you post your request to this url? https://postb.in/1566477083083-7610830974299 and you can check the results here https://postb.in/b/1566477083083-7610830974299

Comment: btw let me know when you have done it so that I can checkout what you are posting

Comment: ok with what data you want me post ,like the answer you suggested or i was sending before like in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198310/discussion-between-miguel-costa-and-abhishek-sarkar).